# I need to query MYSQL records based on the first characters of values

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I have 1 MYSQL table with 8000 records. I would like to query First name, Middle name, and Last name by the first characters of their full name. For instance, i have 40 rows of records (First name, Middle name, and Last name) which their first character of their name is SSS. My question is, how do i query "SSS" to only return 6 results and when i query "SSS" again i need another 6 results and so on until all the 40 records query ends.

I used the following query but only return the first 6 results and when i query "SSS" the next time, it returns the same results over and over. Please i need your help.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table  
WHERE  (UPPER(FName) LIKE UPPER('S%') 
       AND UPPER(MName) LIKE UPPER('S%') 
       AND UPPER(LName) LIKE UPPER('S%') 
ORDER BY ID 
LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to increase the offset to get different results

Answer (score 0):

You're ordering by ID - good. Remember max ID of the last returned data set and when you query next time add condition ID > your_last_max_id

Comment: That was general sql answer... in your mysql case you can simply increase offset!

Comment: Ivan, can you post an example of how to accomplish this by using MAX ID? Is it possible to solve the problem i faced by using 1 query?

Comment: 1 query - no. You'll have to store the state (last offset or max id) somewhere. I don't know what your overall problem is but for example you could store max id in a table. Assuming it's last_max_id in table table1 and you initilized it with 0, you'll need 2 queries to accomplish this:

Comment: SELECT FName,MName,LName,@last_max_id:=ID  FROM Table, table1.t1  WHERE UPPER(FName) LIKE 'S%'  AND UPPER(MName) LIKE 'S%'  AND UPPER(LName) LIKE 'S%'  AND ID > t1.last_max_id  ORDER BY ID  LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0;    UPDATE table1 SET last_max_id=@last_max_id

Comment: I have tried the above query with no hope. it doesn't return any results at all.   This is the query i tried:    SELECT FName, MName, LName, @last_max_id:=ID FROM condowinner, table1 WHERE UPPER(FName) LIKE 'S%' AND UPPER(MName) LIKE 'S%' AND UPPER(LName) LIKE 'S%' AND ID > table1.last_max_id ORDER BY ID LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0; UPDATE table1 SET last_max_id=@last_max_id

Comment: I believe you forgot to initialize table1.last_max_id. Insert 0 and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Second time, change offset:

```
LIMIT 6 OFFSET 6
```

and then

```
LIMIT 6 OFFSET 12
```

etc.